# Any GUI testing/automation tool that works with IBM ILOG Views?

Tags: user-interface, testing, automation, view, ilog

I'm trying to test/automate a tool which GUI is developed with [IBM ILOG Views](http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/visualization/views/). I've tried several tools, but they seem not to work with this application.

Does anyone know a tool that could work with this application?

I've to test also a similar application with a GUI in Java, it would be great if I could test this one with the same tool also.

Thanks,

Comment: Your ask is to launch automated test ? Not manual tests ?Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I did not find any tool for automatic test. I am not working with it anymore, so good luck